# Disable "Window is Ready" Notification in Gnome Shell?

Tags: gnome, notifications, gnome-shell

It's just annoying. I know what happens on my system and if I want to check a software, I can do it on my own. Though I don't know how to disable that. Turning off every notification panel doesn't change a single thing. Turning off notifications doesn't change anything. Does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: I have this problem whenever I click on a link on any application other than a browser. For example, in a mail application, I click on a link, and instead of a browser appearing, I get this notification. I can't understand why it would be desirable to have a notification instead of the actual browser open...

Comment: Well the fact that when you disable notifications, those still appears annoys me to the highest possible point.

Comment: [related](https://askubuntu.com/q/80969/184892)

Comment: Appears to be caused by one of your windows having "always on top" set, even if it's minimized.

Comment: This question is 6 years old, and has been long resolved by the new Gnome versions

Comment: This is back and it's driving me mad.  When I click on a text document I clearly want to open it, not have a damn silly message telling me that it's ready.  Or when I click on reconcile in gnucash, I want to go direct to that window.  I'm running 21.04 and this has only just started happening, so either it is a result of a software update or I've inadvertently changed my settings, but if the latter I've no idea how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a gnome shell extension called [Steal my Focus](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/234/steal-my-focus/) which disables this behavior but it doesn't seem to be supported by the developer anymore. You can make it work though by forking the [git repository](https://github.com/kagesenshi/gnome-shell-extension-stealmyfocus), editing the `metadata.json` file and adding your gnome-shell version in there. Here is mine:

```
{
    "_generated": "Generated by SweetTooth, do not edit",
    "description": "Let windows steal focus. Removes the annoying 'Window is ready' notification and focus window immediately",
    "name": "Steal My Focus",
    "original-authors": [
         "kagesenshi.87@gmail.com"
    ],
    "shell-version": [
         "3.2","3.5.2","3.6","3.6.2","3.7","3.8","3.10","3.10.1"
    ],
    "url": "https://github.com/kagesenshi/gnome-shell-extension-stealmyfocus",
    "uuid": "steal-my-focus@kagesenshi.org",
    "version": 1
}
```

Comment: Though I don't want the window to auto-focus. I just don't want to get notified. (Because it's just annoying) Is there a way to modify that extension so that it doesn't focus ?

Comment: It is but I don't have the knowledge to mofidy it myself. I understand JavaScript but I don't know much about Gnome Shell's JS API

Comment: Yeah me neither xD
I'll just deal with it or wait until Gnome Developpers update the Notification stuff.    
Thanks for your help. I'll validate your answer.

Answer (score 22):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences auto-raise 'true'
```

For anyone viewing this question recently, and willing to accept the newly opened window to rise on top of other open windows.

Comment: This worked for me on Pop!_OS 20.04 / gnome 3.36.8.

Comment: Yes, this is the one, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems this doesn't solve it on Debian 11 / GNOME 3.38.6.

Comment: Nope, with GNOME 43 I still get the 'window is ready' notifications, and the window is not in focus.
NoAnnoyance v2 as mentioned in a different answer solves it as far as I can see.

Comment: Seemingly flawless functionality on Fedora 38 (tested by running `gnome-control-center`). No notification, the window appears on focus.

Comment: Works on Zorin OS 16.2 after restarting.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04, doesn't work.

Comment: Ubuntu 23.10, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 11):

The answer I arrived at is to install this Gnome Extension:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1007/window-is-ready-notification-remover/

Discovered while participating in this issue:

https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Desktop/issues/3321

Comment: Best solution since it does not modify any other behaviour; it just disables the notification.

Comment: This extension doesn't support the newer GNOME versions.

Comment: @Flimm - I recently discovered the same problem with other extensions - assuming you're referring to this:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418937/your-native-host-connector-do-not-support-following-apis-v6

Comment: @odigity I'm not referring to that, I mean it's not even possible to install this extension on Ubuntu 23.10 (with GNOME 45), because the installer won't let you install the extension on this unsupported version of GNOME. If you have a look at the extension's page, you can see in the dropdown control next to "Download" that the newest version of GNOME that it supports is GNOME 43.

Answer (score 8):

You're observing GNOME's focus stealing prevention kicking it. A background app wants to steal the focus (i.e., put one of its windows in focus) but GNOME's heuristics determine that the request is not based on a current user interaction, so the currently focused window should keep its focus.

This GNOME extension will mute the notification:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1007/window-is-ready-notification-remover/

If you instead would like to disable focus stealing prevention, i.e., you want the window mentioned in the notification to actually get the focus, then use this extension instead:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2182/noannoyance/

For more background:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/673

(The above comment was written by user [real-or-random](https://superuser.com/users/404598/real-or-random) as a replacement for my answer - and then reverted back - when it should have just been added as another answer.  I am posting it on their behalf so it's not lost.)

Comment: this ones great. Recently switched to gnome3 and this popup problem just saved me a nightmare. Thanks

Comment: These extensions don't support the newer versions of GNOME.

Answer (score 3):

In Gnome 3.18, there is an option in `gnome-tweak-tool` to automatically focus on the window instead of displaying this annoying notifications.

Comment: Could you clarify which option this is?

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Not found in gnome-tweak with Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2):

I've found another half-measure: another extension which is not stealing focus, but providing a keyboard shortcut for showing the "ready" application/dialog: https://github.com/awamper/window-demands-attention-shortcut

Default shortcut is `Super-W` and it is configurable in gnome-tweak-tool.

Comment: It worked with Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 2):

Here is a similar extension that works on newer versions of gnome-shell (tested on 3.16) https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1005/focus-my-window/

Comment: The link seems to be broken, I get a 404 error.

Comment: 7 years ago, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use dconf-editor
2. Set property "/org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/focus-new-windows" to "strict"
3. Apply changes
4. Enjoy

Comment: this just removed notification.... but window still not showing up... :(((